# Print lines from a file based on the index in other file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file (`myFile`) with 20000 lines and another file (`myIndex`) like this containing the lines that must be extracted from `myFile`:

```
 4
 10
 1200
 ..
 ..
```

I want to extract these lines with `sed`:

```
sed '10!d' myFile
```

How can I put the file name instead of `4,10` like this:

```
sed 'myIndex!d' myFile
```

Or is there a similar function in awk?

Comment: What is the meaning of the `1200`?

Comment: line 1200, I  should extract line 4, 10, 1200 and ... from myFile.

Comment: `sed 4,10!d` returns lines 4-10, it **doesn't** return lines 4 *and* 10

Comment: edited. sed '10!d' myFile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using awk to pull specific lines from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182910/using-awk-to-pull-specific-lines-from-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -nf <(sed 's/.*/&p/' myIndex) myFile
```

---

`-n`: suppress automatic printing of pattern space

`-f`: add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed

`<(...)`: bash's [Process Substitution](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35)

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{i[$0];next}i[FNR]' index file
```

`NR==FNR` is true as long as we are reading the first while `index`. We are storing all that line numbers in an array `i`. On the remaining input we are checking if the line number is stored in `i`. If that is true, awk prints that line.