# How to use Awk to output multiple consecutive lines

Tags: awk

Input/File

```
A:1111
B:21222
C:33rf33
D:444dct4
E:5tdffe
F:4444we
G:j5555
H:46666
I:efe989ef
J:efee
```

Basically need to select the line that contains 2122 (i.e line B/2)
& line which starts with 444dct4 (i.e Line D) till efe989ef (i.e line I/9)
To summarize

```
Select Line B (contains 2122)
Select Line D (444dct4) till Line I
```

Desired Output

```
B:21222
D:444dct4
E:5tdffe
F:4444we
G:j5555
H:46666
I:efe989ef
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO. Also please do explain Logic of getting expected output more clearly in your question.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182910/using-awk-to-pull-specific-lines-from-a-file

Comment: Also, do you want _the line that contains 2122 **OR** (i.e line B **OR** 2)_

Comment: Thanks James. The line that contains 2122

Comment: @KarimTawfik I suppose the question is relating to 2 separate files if i am understanding correctly. I need have a single file & need the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v str1="2122" -v str2="444dct4" -v str3="efe989ef" 'BEGIN { flag=0 } $0 ~ str1 { print } $0 ~ str2 { flag=1 } $0 ~ str3 { flag=0;print;next } flag' file
```

For flexibility, set the line to find as str1, the from as str2 and the to as str3. Set a print flag (flag) to begin with. When 2122 is in the second field print. Then when the second field begins with 44dct4 set the print flag to one. When the second field starts with efe989ef, set the print flag to 0, print the line and skip to the next record. The variable flag will then determine what does and doesn't get printed.

Comment: thanks Raman. I couldnt get this worked. could you share the command that works for you

Comment: The same command as above. I used the example sample you posted. I also verified that the output was as required.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This one also takes care in case line's 2nd column `21222` in between range of `444dct4` to `efe989ef` then it will NOT re-print it.

```
awk -F':' '
$2=="21222" && !found{
  print
  next
}
$2=="444dct4"{
  found=1
}
found
$2=="efe989ef"{
  found=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F':' '              ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as colon here.
$2=="21222" && !found{   ##Checking if 2nd field is 21222 and found is NOT set then try following.
  print                  ##Printing the current line here.
  next                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
$2=="444dct4"{           ##Checking condition if 2nd field is 444dct4 then do following.
  found=1                ##Setting found to 1 here.
}
found                    ##Checking condition if found is SET then print that line.
$2=="efe989ef"{          ##Checking condition if 2nd field is efe989ef then do following.
  found=""               ##Nullifying found here.
}
'  Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: thanks. i tried but no output. could you share the command that works for you

Comment: @PrasadV, This solution is a tested solution and worked fine for me with shown samples of yours. Is your actual Input_file it same as shown samples?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F: '
/2122/ {                      # line that contains 2122
    print                  
    next                      # to avoid duplicate printing if 2122 also in D-I
}
$2~/^444dct4/,$2~/efe989ef/   # starts with 444dct4 till efe989ef
' file
```

Output:

```
B:21222
D:444dct4
E:5tdffe
F:4444we
G:j5555
H:46666
I:efe989ef
```

**Edit**:

One-liner:

```
$ awk -F: '/2122/{print; next} $2~/^444dct4/,$2~/efe989ef/' file.txt
```

Comment: awk -F: ' /2122/ { printnext } $2~ /^444dct4/,$2~ /efe989ef/' file.txt

Comment: Output starts with D & ends till I. Cannot see B in the output

Comment: `/2122/ { printnext }` needs a `;` inbetween: `/2122/ {print; next}`